# PHP script stop around completing 10 records

Tags: php, curl

Below is my php script to read a json file and then call the API with passing the json records as parameter, it always stop after the 10th call, I do the count to the json record and return 61 but only the first 10 be processed.

```
function apipost($post_data) {
    $url = "https://example.com/api/";
    $options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,    
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,    // for https
    //CURLOPT_USERPWD        => $loginusername . ":" . $loginpassword,
    //CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH       => CURLAUTH_DIGEST,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($post_data) ,
    );


    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    try {
        $raw_response  = curl_exec( $ch );
        $headerSize = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($raw_response, 0, $headerSize);
        $body = substr($raw_response, $headerSize);

        if(curl_errno($ch))
        {
            return;
        }
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if ($status_code != 200)
        {  
            return;
        }
    } catch(Exception $ex) {
        if ($ch != null) curl_close($ch);
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ($ch != null) {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}

$path = 'access_post.json';
$jsonString = file_get_contents($path);
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString, true);

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
foreach($jsonData['data'] as $post_data) {
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    $post_new_data = array(
        'state' => $post_data['state'],
        'cmd' => $post_data['cmd'],
        'card_id' =>  $post_data['cardid'],
        'timestamp' =>  $post_data['timestamp']
    );
    printf("%s<br>", json_encode($post_new_data)); 
    apipost($post_new_data);
            
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

function `apipost()` prepares the cURL and calls the external API.

Anyone can advise me whether it was broken by the PHP script or the server-side resource issue?

P.S. api is located on same website.

Comment: Can you remove all output buffering related calls and try again? Not sure why it's needed in the first place.

Comment: Share `apipost` code and also some sample data, so we better debug and suggest solution. BTW why do you required `ob_start` methods?

Comment: My guess is the API has a rate limit and you're exceeding it.

Comment: apipost() added. @Hassaanthe ob_ function is used to display the progress instead of waiting for the completion of whole php script.

Comment: @Barmar I think so but no idea how to increase its rate limit. Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't increase its rate limit, you slow down your client.